# Is there a way to merge Facebook's /me/statuses , /me/home , me/feeds?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to display on a website all of these 3.  I haven't found a way of doing so together, only in 3 separate sections.

I was reading there is a way of querying but not sure how to build this query to pull all 3  (me/statuses , me/home , me/feed) and have them in chronological order and show comments/likes as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your app will have to loop through the results and merge them as needed. You might want to  use Batch requests so you only have to make 1 request and not 3, however the data will still come back un-merged.